# Trimming a string until a value

Tags: sql, sql-server, trim

I ve got a column which has different sized strings, looking like:

```
abcd, efgh, ijkl2, 2345, xyzw
```

I need to trim it into 2 different columns, and get the string before the comma from right and then the other one, so I will have 2 other columns with:

```
2345    xyz
```

I ve tried to get only the first part of the string before the first comma:

```
RTRIM(LTRIM(RIGHT(A.[column],charindex(',',A.[column]+',')-1))) as 'aa'

RIGHT(A.[column], len(A.[column]) - charindex(',',A.[column])) as 'ab'
```

But I get it mixed, sometimes I get some of the values after the comma, but incomplete.

Any thoughts?

Thank you, I appreciate it.

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server, what are you really using here? This looks like SQL Server, but considering you tagged MySQL first...

Comment: you can use string_split if you are one sql server 2016 or more,  https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: `STRING_SPLIT` suggested by @Esperento57 doesn't give you the original position; vital for this operation. There are probably quite a few examples on how to do this on SO, however, look at [DelimitedSplit8k](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)

Comment: Have a look here https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40930/extract-part-of-string-based-on-nth-instance-of-character

Comment: of course you can, with a row_number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such string functions in SQL Server are really painful.  I like to use `apply` for such operations, because this makes it easier to keep intermediate results.

For this particular problem:

```
select v.str, v2.lastval, v3.secondlastval
from (values ('abcd, efgh, ijkl2, 2345, xyzw')) v(str) cross apply
     (select stuff(str, 1, len(str) - charindex(',', reverse(str)) + 2, ''),
             stuff(str, len(str) - charindex(',', reverse(str)) + 1, len(str), '')
             ) v2(lastval, rest) cross apply
     (select stuff(v2.rest, 1, len(v2.rest) - charindex(',', reverse(v2.rest)) + 2, ''),
             stuff(v2.rest, len(v2.rest) - charindex(',', reverse(v2.rest)) + 1, len(v2.rest), '')
             ) v3(secondlastval, rest);
```

Having said that, you should probably reconsider your data structure.  Storing lists of values in delimited strings is a poor data structure in SQL because SQL does not have very good string processing capabilities.  Instead, you should be using a junction/association table.

Answer (score 0):

you can use string_split if you are one sql server 2016...

try Something like this :

```
drop TABLE REC.TestTable;
CREATE TABLE REC.TestTable (id int identity, --Avoid using keywords for column names
                            str varchar(500));

GO

INSERT INTO REC.TestTable (str)
VALUES ('abcd, efgh, ijkl2, 123, ijk'),
       ('abcd, efgh, ijkl2, 4567, lmn'),
       ('abcd, efgh, ijkl2, 89, opqr')
;
GO

with tmp as (
select f1.*, f2.value, row_number() over(partition by id order by (select null)) position
from REC.TestTable f1 cross apply STRING_SPLIT(str, ',') f2
)
select f1.*, f2.value ValPos1, f3.value ValPos2, f4.value ValPos3, f5.value ValPos4, f6.value ValPos5   
from REC.TestTable f1
left outer join tmp f2 on f1.id=f2.id and f2.position =1
left outer join tmp f3 on f1.id=f3.id and f3.position =2
left outer join tmp f4 on f1.id=f4.id and f4.position =3
left outer join tmp f5 on f1.id=f5.id and f5.position =4
left outer join tmp f6 on f1.id=f6.id and f6.position =5
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! It s a good approach, but Gordon s reply is more flexible and uses less resources.

Comment: yes but for gordon solution, you must have necessary 5 elements into every rows ;)